# How do I use dumpbin to look for RCS keywords on a DLL file?

Tags: rcs

In my code,

I add some RCS keywords, like "$Header$", "$Author$", etc., and compile it to DLL file

Is there anyway I could look inside the DLL for these RCS keywords using "dumpbin" function from VS studio 2012?

OR

There is better solution, that I do not know about?